# Valid Excel Custom Number with trailing comma treated as Malformed by DecimalFormat

Tags: java, excel, decimalformat

The following is a valid Custom Number Format in Excel: **#,##0.0,**

Please note the trailing comma. It allows Excel to scale a number down by 1000;

similarly double comma at the end scale a number down by million.

However, in Java, using DecimalFormat when I create this format (as shown below in code, it throws an exception with message: Malformed pattern **"#,##0.0,"**

```
String format="#,##0.0,";

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(format);
```

Is there any way to create this DecimalFormat which will perform this scale down?

For Example, if I apply the same pattern in Excel to a number 705.0, the result shown in Excel is 0.7

That is what I am expecting as output after performing :

```
String result = df.format(new Double(705.0));
```

If there is no way, I am hoping I would achieve the result by manually dividing by 1000, before applying the format: #,##0.0

Comment: This is csv right? Are you using any library like Apache POI etc? They can pull numeric values from cells like that.

Comment: The data is coming from Excel and I am using Apache POI to read the data. However, turns out that POI internally uses DecimalFormat to create a NumberFormat to format the cell's value. And because it is a Malformed pattern as per DeciamlFormat, POI falls back to default number format (which is not what I want to display).

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix for this would be to just create your own subclass of NumberFormat that uses a DecimalFormat internally but also tracks those ending commas. Something like

```
public class ExcelFormat extends NumberFormat {
  private DecimalFormat df;
  private int endingCommas;

  public ExcelFormat(String format) {
    //calculate the ending commas. Remove from format
    //create df using the substring with the commas removed
  }

  public String format(double number, StringBuffer buf, FieldPosition fp) {
    //divide the number by what's indicated by the endingCommas
    return df.format(adjustedNumber);
  }
```

}